# VueJs Typescript ignore typescript error in template block

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In my VueJs App everything works as expected. Only thing annoying me is a typescript error in my template block. Is there any option similar to what I would do in my script block?

```bash
<script setup lang="ts">
//@ignore-ts
this line will be ignored of typescript errors
</script>

<template>
<!-- @ignore-ts -->
this does not work and this line still has a typescript error
</template>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `<!-- @vue-ignore -->` [#3215](https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/pull/3215). For example:

```html
<template>
  <!-- @vue-ignore -->
  <HelloWorld :msg="wrongType" />

  <!-- @vue-expect-error Describe your error here -->
  <HelloWorld :msg="wrongType" />

  <!-- @vue-skip -->
  <SomethingYouDontWantVolarToRecognizeIt>
    ...
  </SomethingYouDontWantVolarToRecognizeIt>
</template>
```

Answer (score 10):

I found my solution finally. `//@ts-ignore` is still the solution for my problem but most importantly an `Enter` afterwards makes its magic happen.

If a typescript error annoys you in a `v-if=""`,`v-model=""`,`v-for=""` etc. in your template block, you can ignore it like this:

**Typescript error throwing line of code:**

```
<div v-if="value.input_type === 'text'">
```

**Typescript error ignoring lines of code:**

```
<div v-if="//@ts-ignore 
    value.input_type === 'text'">
```

If a typescript error annoys you in a mustache i.e. double curly braces in your template block do this:

**Typescript error throwing line of code:**

```
<h3>{{value.label }}</h3>
```

**Typescript error ignoring lines of code:**

```
<h3>{{//@ts-ignore
       value.label }}</h3>
```

Comment: reporting that this didn't work for me using `vue: "^3.2.47"`. instead i moved the logic that was displaying a type-check error out of the `<template>` by creating a `const ref()` in the `<script>` and utilizing `//@ts-ignore` on the line directly above.

Comment: How do I do this for directives?

```<template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">```

Array brackets generate a TS 2538 error

```Type 'string[]' cannot be used as an index type.```

Comment: I would try one of these two options 
1. `<template v-slot:[\`//@ts-ignore` **\n i.e. new line here**
                     `item.actions\`]="{ item }"> `
2. `<template v-slot:[\`item.actions\`]={//@ts-ignore` **\n i.e. new line here**
                    `item }">`
Does this work for you?

Comment: The proper fix is to solve the underlying typescript error. There's always a way to instruct Typescript of your intentions so you allow it to keep doing its job. That's the question you should have asked, IMHO. The only time you'd want to shut Typescript up would be with a false positive, which should be reported to Typescript anyways, so it gets fixed.

Comment: @tao I completely agree with you. However, when I posted this I was learning Vue AND Typescript and I was happy everything was running in my app in Vue and the only thing missing was that one annoying Typescript error I had to get rid of by understanding Typescript well enough. I think thats the main situation when people are looking for this thread. I see this as an interim solution for development.

Comment: @tao, I almost always agree, but I have a similar case where I have an event handler that needs to pass the event's value into another function along with values from a v-for loop, using a closure technique, like: `value => myMethod(value, key, nestedKey)` where `key` and `nestedKey` are keys from an object I was iterating on. The error is that `value` wasn't typed and I can't do that without Vue throwing syntax errors. Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: @Ozzy, I suggest posting it as a separate question in the form of *"how can I properly type X"*, rather than *"how to ignore type error Y"*. Provide a link to it once asked and, if I know how, I'll answer. I suggest providing a *runnable* [mcve] along with the question, in codesandbox.io or similar, since you probably need a node-like online environment to repro.

Comment: @tao true, but the answer here was what I needed because I'm fairly confident that the issue is beyond TypeScript; it's Volar VS Code extension causing issues where the extension's TS version is claiming there is a linting issue, but I can't fix it because it's in the template. In other words, I don't really need an answer, just curious if there was already an existing solution out there.

Comment: @Ozzy, what I was saying is that it's a lot more likely to find an answer to that question by properly asking it than by asking under someone else's answer to a different question. Just imagine everyone would ask questions as you just did and, for the sake of argument, imagine they would actually get them answered. And then imagine how hard finding the answer you're looking for would be, if StackOverflow was used as such. Even if I did understand your problem fully, which I didn't, I wouldn't answer it in a comment, on general principles. No offence meant, I'm trying to be friendly here :)

Answer (score 0):

The error probably shown by TSLint/ESLint, so you can disable this validations.
You can use

```
/* tslint:disable */
```

and

```
/* tslint:enable */
```

(this can be applied only on the line or block that have errors.
Or you can only disable specifics rules, see more details [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/)

But, I strongly recommend to you search about the error and if there are a correct way to implement it (I know it doesn't always have)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this doesn't help me yet. If I use `/* tslint:disable */` in my <script>-block, there is still an error thrown in my <template> block. I have posted my actual typescript problem in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74490975/vuejs-typescript-v-model-type-number-is-not-assignable-to-type-nullablestrin) if you might want to check it.